# How to run updating in migration for Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I use [Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/) and [Ecto](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto) in one of my project.

I want to add a column to one table, and I expect it to be a *NOT NULL* column. But I already have some existed data, so I decide to add the column, update all rows to some value and modify the column to *NOT NULL*.

I tried these two code:

```
  # solution 1
  def up do
    alter table(:channels) do
      add :type, :integer
      Exchat.Repo.update_all("channels", set: [type: 1])
      modify :type, :integer, null: false
    end
  end

  # solution 2
  def up do
    alter table(:channels) do
      add :type, :integer
    end
    Exchat.Repo.update_all("channels", set: [type: 1])
    alter table(:channels) do
      modify :type, :integer, null: false
    end
  end
```

Both of them didn't work and I got error like:

```
23::40::07.514 [info]  == Running Exchat.Repo.Migrations.AddTypeToChannels.up/0 forward

23::40::07.541 [debug] UPDATE "channels" AS c0 SET "type" = $1 [1] ERROR query=12.0ms
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (undefined_column): column "type" of relation "channels" does not exist
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:383: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_and_cache/7
```

I'm not sure if it's related to the Ecto version but my Ecto version is 2.0.0-rc.0.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or is there something wrong in my example code?

Comment: Try adding `flush()` after the first `alter do end` in your solution #2. Does that work?

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: Hm... The same code raise `** (ArgumentError) argument error`. What can be wrong? gist - https://gist.github.com/maslenkov/1ca80dbc913f92a9334a6545eb89880e

Comment: Ok. It is a problem with elixometer. I think I'll post issue there...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Solution #2 is the correct approach, but you need to add a call to [`Ecto.Migration.flush/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#flush/0) after the first `alter` block to make sure all the changes are executed on the database instantly instead of being queued up to be executed later, which is the default.

```
def up do
  alter table(:channels) do
    add :type, :integer
  end
  flush()
  Exchat.Repo.update_all("channels", set: [type: 1])
  alter table(:channels) do
    modify :type, :integer, null: false
  end
end
```